# Determine memory usage of an std::map/std::set at runtime

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

Is it possible to determine the real memory usage of an std::map/std::set (of intrinsic data types) at runtime? I made some memory studies and it seems that this highly depends on the STL implementation and on the system which is used (due to memory padding of the underlying structs). I would like to monitor the memory usage of these data types at runtime, without running a debugger/memory profiler. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should use STL to store pointers anyway

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I do not understand your comment. How is it related to the question?

Comment: In other words, stdlib containers aren't guaranteed not to copy or move your data. You should store pointers to your objects in them.

Comment: The question is related to intrinsic data type, i.e. integer, long, double, etc.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I don't know how did I miss it actually.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz And even if not, it is perfectly your decision what objects you store in your containers and their memory footprint with respect to the stored type doesn't change, no matter if using pointers, doubles or MagicSuperObjects. Using pointers instead of values is as a general advice just complete rubbish and depends on the particular type and situation. And there are also obvious guarantees you can deduce from the container types, since the standard makes assertions about reallocation and complexity (and nobody copies elements without reason, even if allowed to by the standard).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement a custom allocator which will count the memory used, and provide that to the constructor of your map/set.

Comment: Is there any short introduction online how to write a custom allocator for this purposes?

Comment: Note: it is relatively hard to correlate the memory truly used and the impact on the memory consumed by the process because of (possibly) fragmentation in the allocation.